# Avoiding duplicates of a specific column in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following method for pulling out all the data from my database. However in my database there is a column called `media_id`. I want to make sure that it only fetches data where the `media_id` is unique. If there is a duplicate based on the `media_id` column, it just needs to pick the first one it runs into and disregard all the rest. Anyone have any suggestions how I do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public function getAllValuesFromOneTable($table1, $fromDate, $toDate) {
    try {
        $statement = $this->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM $table1 WHERE date_of_post >= '$fromDate' AND date_of_post <= '$toDate'");
        $statement->execute();
        $test = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $test;
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
select distinct media_id
```

(and if the filename is in a separate field, add this column to the query)
This way if the table would be

```
12
54
234
65
12
234
```

It only returns:

```
12
54
65
234
```

Answer (score 0):

you can group your results in sql search by media_id

```
SELECT * FROM $table1 WHERE date_of_post >= '$fromDate' AND date_of_post <= '$toDate' group by media_id
```